# universal.angular.io vs prerender.io from googlebot perspective

Tags: javascript, angular, googlebot, prerender, server-side-rendering

I have a setup of a website with Angular 1.4.x and prerender.io that serves the rendered static cached pages to googlebot.
Googlebot crawls each page twice. One crawl hit the URL and the second crawl is appending ?_escaped_fragment_ to url to get the cached static page from prerender.io

I'm thinking on moving to universal.angular.io which will render the page in the server side.

What are the different approaches between the two?
Does universal.angular.io server side rendering support serving to googlebot and to end-clients?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Well for something like Prerender, the way it works is by hijacking the AJAX crawl by search engines and serving it a prerendered version that they have cached. In this case only the search bot sees the prerendering. (I believe that `?_escaped_fragment_` is what trigger is, but it's treated by the crawler as the same route as the one without it)

If you migrate your application to Angular (2 or greater) and use Angular Universal, you'll allow your server to render out the pages that get sent to both the search bots as well as the regular user. Nixing the need for the `?_escaped_fragment_`.